# How to loop through a table with a variable string as the table name?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am a beginner in Microsoft Access and VBA and I am currently working on a model where I have about 150+ chip ID tables. I have a textbox/combo box on a form for user to select a certain chip ID. After selecting what chip ID they want, I have VBA running in the background to check the table with the same name as the chip ID. I managed to do so by declaring a variable as string and used Dlookup. I also used recordset to create a new table which combines the data together.

Here's my VBA code:

```
Private Sub APLCombo_AfterUpdate()

    Dim I
          
    TestQ APLCombo.ItemData(I)

End Sub


Public Sub TestQ(APL)

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim MatchingTable As String
Dim A As String
Dim L As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Test")
A = APLCombo.Value

For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
   If tdf.Name Like CStr(A) Then
      MatchingTable = tdf.Name
      Exit For
   End If
Next

For L = 1 To 30
    rs.AddNew
    rs!OrderID = Text35
    rs!APL = APLCombo
    rs!Type = Text52
    rs!SystemID = DLookup("SEQUENCE", MatchingTable, "SEQUENCE = " & L)
    rs.Update
    End If
    Next

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing


End Sub
```

So far the recordset table would look like this:

```
OrderID    |     APL     |     Type     |     SystemID     
1          |     123     |      A       |     1     
1          |     123     |      A       |     2     
1          |     123     |      A       |     3
.
.
.
1          |     123     |      A       |     17
1          |     123     |      A       |     
1          |     123     |      A       |    
1          |     123     |      A       |
```

The code works fine and it doesn't show any errors. But my only problem is that the code will continue looping 30 times even though there are only 17 records in this particular chip ID table. I tried using .EOF but it doesn't work since I'm using MatchingTable as the string variable name of the table. Is there any way I can solve this issue?

Comment: *I have about 150+ chip ID tables* -- don't do this, it will be a maintenance nightmare. Use **one** table where ChipID is a column.

Comment: That's another issue though, because for each chip ID, there are multiple procedures on how to make them and there's a separate table for the 500++ procedures

Comment: 500+ procedure tables?  That will be a maintenance nightmare to.  I'd use one table with the chip ID as a foreign key linking to the single chip ID table (where chip ID is the primary key).

Comment: Ah no, for the procedures, they are all kept in one table since there are wayyy too many. But I made individual tables for the chip IDs since they're much fewer and less "updating"

Comment: From there, all the procedures of each chip ID is linked to the procedure table where the procedures are the primary key

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to the number of records in table.

```
x = DCount(MatchingTable)
For L = 1 to x
```

Or possibly use an INSERT SELECT sql statement instead of looping and adding records to recordset with DLookup(). I am guessing APL and Type are text fields.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Test(OrderID, APL, Type, SystemID) " & _
    "SELECT " & Me.Text35 & ",'" & Me.APLCombo & "','" & Me.Text52 & "', SEQUENCE FROM [" _
    & MatchingTable & "]"
```